# Xtext custom validator warning - How to mark keyword?

Tags: validation, warnings, xtext, xtend

I have the simple Greeting example in xtext. So the DSL is defined like this:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.Tests with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate tests "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/Tests"

Model:
    greetings+= Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Hello' name=ID '!';
```

Moreover, I have the following validator:

```
@Check
def checkGreetingStartsWithCapital(Greeting greeting) {
    if (!Character.isUpperCase(greeting.name.charAt(0))) {
        warning('Name should start with a capital', 
                TestsPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME,
                -1,
                INVALID_NAME)
    }
}
```

If I write the validator like this and have an expression like
        "Hello world!"
in my model, the "world" is marked, i.e. there is this yellow line under it. What do I have to do if I want to mark only the keyword so in this case only the "Hello"? 
I tried quite a few things and I can only manage to either mark the whole line "Hello world!" or just the "world".

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at the other methods for reporting a warning/error. there is one that takes an offset and length. you can use the node model to get them for the keyword

```
class MyDslValidator extends AbstractMyDslValidator {

    public static val INVALID_NAME = 'invalidName'
    @Inject extension MyDslGrammarAccess

    @Check
    def checkGreetingStartsWithCapital(Greeting greeting) {
        if (!Character.isUpperCase(greeting.name.charAt(0))) {
            val node = NodeModelUtils.findActualNodeFor(greeting)

            for (n : node.asTreeIterable) {
                val ge = n.grammarElement
                if (ge instanceof Keyword && ge == greetingAccess.helloKeyword_0) {
                    messageAcceptor.acceptWarning(
                        'Name should start with a capital',
                        greeting,
                        n.offset,
                        n.length,
                        INVALID_NAME
                    )
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update this answer? It seems like these days the validator API looks quite different.

Comment: @BalzGuenat what do you mean. the code is still perfectly fine

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Hm, I was somehow under the impression that the `warning()` method had replaced the acceptor pattern. Is this not the case, then? Is one of the two ways preferred? How would I do the above with `warning()`?

Comment: you use warning. except you have EXACTLY this usecase

Comment: @ChristianDietrich In contrast to other ways of marking things in XText, this seems pretty clumsy for a fairly common use case. Is this still the best way?

Comment: marking keywords and not assigning them in the grammar is still a uncommon usecase.

Answer (score 1):

I found another very simple solution I haven't thought of that includes changing the DSL a bit, i.e. add the keyword as a attribute.

```
Greeting:
    keyword='Hello' name=ID '!';
```

Then the validator works as in the question:

```
@Check
def checkGreetingStartsWithCapital(Greeting greeting) {
    if (!Character.isUpperCase(greeting.name.charAt(0))) {
        warning('Name should start with a capital', 
                TestsPackage.Literals.GREETING__KEYWORD,
                -1,
                INVALID_NAME)
    }
}
```